# Trouble printing table of results

Tags: java, output

I am trying to get it to print a list of results every time the time is a whole number (ei, 2.0, 4.0, 12.0, etc) but it only prints the first line of results. Is the if condition wrong? or my command for printing the values?

package a03;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Calvin (A00391077) this program simulates a cannon firing at presets
 * set by the user.
 */
public class Cannon {

```
public static final double DELTA_T = 0.001;
public static final double GRAVITY = 9.81;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //variables
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    double muzzleVelocity, muzzleHeight, time, height, velocity;

    //introducing program
    System.out.println("Cannon Simulation");
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This program simulates firing a cannon straight"
            + "up into the air. Velocity");
    System.out.println("is measured in metres per second squared and"
            + " height in meteres.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("By Calvin Elliott (A00391077");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("...press enter...");
    kbd.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    //getting muzzle velocity
    System.out.println("What is the muzzle velocity of the projectile?");
    muzzleVelocity = kbd.nextDouble();

    while (muzzleVelocity <= 0) {
        System.out.println("The velocity must be positive");
        System.out.println("What is the muzzle velocity of the projectile?");
        muzzleVelocity = kbd.nextDouble();
    }

    //getting muzzle height
    System.out.println("what height is the muzzle above the ground?");
    muzzleHeight = kbd.nextDouble();

    while (muzzleHeight <= 0) {
        System.out.println("The position must be positive");
        System.out.println("What height is the muzzle above the ground?");
        muzzleHeight = kbd.nextDouble();

    }

    //calculations
    height = muzzleHeight;
    velocity = muzzleVelocity;
    time = 0;

    System.out.println("TIME    HEIGHT    VELOCITY");
    System.out.println("----    ------    --------");

    while (height > 0) {
        if ((time % 1.0) < DELTA_T) {
            System.out.printf("%6.2f%10.3f%10.3f\n", time, height, velocity);

        }
        height = (height + (velocity * time));
        velocity = (velocity - (GRAVITY * time));
        time = (time + 0.001);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried time % 1.0 == 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are increasing the height by the `velocity * time`, which is the absolute amount of time each iteration.   You need to increment it instead by the time increment `DELTA_T`

For example:

```
while (height > 0) {
    if ((time % 1.0) < DELTA_T) {
        System.out.printf("%6.2f%10.3f%10.3f\n", time, height, velocity);

    }
    height = (height + (velocity * DELTA_T));
    velocity = (velocity - (GRAVITY * DELTA_T));
    time = (time + DELTA_T);

}
```

Also worth noting the gravity should generally be a negative value, so that you can add it to the velocity, same as you add the velocity to the position.

Comment: It all makes so much sense now. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @CalElliott, you are new here. A good practice is to accept the best answer. The check mark on the left...